# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for feed.. i m getting this error.. i m using flickr API

Tags: java, android, json

here is my SplashActivity and JSON Call i m trying to use flickr API.. i have been following a tutorial on wallpaper app..

always getting this error message.. i don't know what to do??

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd.app.AppConst;
import com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd.app.AppController;
import com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd.picasa.model.Category;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String TAG_FEED = "feed", TAG_ENTRY = "entry",
        TAG_GPHOTO_ID = "gphoto$id", TAG_T = "$t",
        TAG_ALBUM_TITLE = "title";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    // Picasa request to get list of albums
    String url = AppConst.URL_FLICKR_ALBUMS
            .replace("_PICASA_USER_", AppController.getInstance()
                    .getPrefManger().getGoogleUserName());

    Log.d(TAG, "Albums request url: " + url);

    // Preparing volley's json object request
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url,
             new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Albums Response: " + response.toString());
            List<Category> albums = new ArrayList<Category>();
            try {
                // Parsing the json response
                JSONArray entry = response.getJSONObject(TAG_FEED)
                        .getJSONArray(TAG_ENTRY);

                // loop through albums nodes and add them to album
                // list
                for (int i = 0; i < entry.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject albumObj = (JSONObject) entry.get(i);
                    // album id
                    String albumId = albumObj.getJSONObject(
                            TAG_GPHOTO_ID).getString(TAG_T);

                    // album title
                    String albumTitle = albumObj.getJSONObject(
                            TAG_ALBUM_TITLE).getString(TAG_T);

                    Category album = new Category();
                    album.setId(albumId);
                    album.setTitle(albumTitle);

                    // add album to list
                    albums.add(album);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Album Id: " + albumId
                            + ", Album Title: " + albumTitle);
                }

                // Store albums in shared pref
                AppController.getInstance().getPrefManger()
                        .storeCategories(albums);

                // String the main activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // closing spalsh activity
                finish();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Volley Error: " + error.getMessage());

            // show error toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.splash_error),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Unable to fetch albums
            // check for existing Albums data in Shared Preferences
            if (AppController.getInstance().getPrefManger()
                    .getCategories() != null && AppController.getInstance().getPrefManger()
                    .getCategories().size() > 0) {
                // String the main activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // closing spalsh activity
                finish();
            } else {
                // Albums data not present in the shared preferences
                // Launch settings activity, so that user can modify
                // the settings

                // Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                //SettingsActivity.class);
                // clear all the activities
                // i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                // | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                //startActivity(i);
            }

        }

    });

    // disable the cache for this request, so that it always fetches updated
    // json
    jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);

    // Making the request
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

}
```

Here is logcat.. here is the error

```
enter code here
10-18 06:17:11.937 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:          org.json.JSONException: No value for feed
10-18 06:17:11.937 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
10-18 06:17:11.937 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
10-18 06:17:11.937 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd.SplashActivity$1.onResponse(SplashActivity.java:55)
10-18 06:17:11.937 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd.SplashActivity$1.onResponse(SplashActivity.java:47)
10-18 06:17:11.937 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:72)
10-18 06:17:11.937 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
10-18 06:17:11.937 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-18 06:17:11.937 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-18 06:17:11.937 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-18 06:17:11.937 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
10-18 06:17:11.938 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-18 06:17:11.938 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-18 06:17:11.938 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
10-18 06:17:11.938 20262-20262/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
10-18 06:17:11.998 20262-20302/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd V/RenderScript: Application requested CPU execution
10-18 06:17:12.002 20262-20302/com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd V/RenderScript: 0x558bec9140 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
```

Need Help

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Wallpaper implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String url, photoJson;
private int width, height;

public Wallpaper() {
}

public Wallpaper(String photoJson, String url, int width, int height) {     
    this.photoJson = photoJson;
    this.url = url;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getPhotoJson() {
    return photoJson;
}

public void setPhotoJson(String photoJson) {
    this.photoJson = photoJson;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}
```

}

here is prefManager

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd.app.AppConst;
import com.shyamdev.animewallpaperhd.picasa.model.Category;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class PrefManager {
private static final String TAG = PrefManager.class.getSimpleName();

// Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor for Shared preferences
Editor editor;

// Context
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "AwesomeWallpapers";

// Google's username
private static final String KEY_GOOGLE_USERNAME = "google_username";

// No of grid columns
private static final String KEY_NO_OF_COLUMNS = "no_of_columns";

// Gallery directory name
private static final String KEY_GALLERY_NAME = "gallery_name";

// gallery albums key
private static final String KEY_ALBUMS = "albums";

public PrefManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);

}

/**
 * Storing google username
 * */
public void setGoogleUsername(String googleUsername) {
    editor = pref.edit();

    editor.putString(KEY_GOOGLE_USERNAME, googleUsername);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
}

public String getGoogleUserName() {
    return pref.getString(KEY_GOOGLE_USERNAME, AppConst.PICASA_USER);
}

/**
 * store number of grid columns
 * */
public void setNoOfGridColumns(int columns) {
    editor = pref.edit();

    editor.putInt(KEY_NO_OF_COLUMNS, columns);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
}

public int getNoOfGridColumns() {
    return pref.getInt(KEY_NO_OF_COLUMNS, AppConst.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
}

/**
 * storing gallery name
 * */
public void setGalleryName(String galleryName) {
    editor = pref.edit();

    editor.putString(KEY_GALLERY_NAME, galleryName);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
}

public String getGalleryName() {
    return pref.getString(KEY_GALLERY_NAME, AppConst.SDCARD_DIR_NAME);
}

/**
 * Storing albums in shared preferences
 * */
public void storeCategories(List<Category> albums) {
    editor = pref.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Log.d(TAG, "Albums: " + gson.toJson(albums));

    editor.putString(KEY_ALBUMS, gson.toJson(albums));

    // save changes
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Fetching albums from shared preferences. Albums will be sorted before
 * returning in alphabetical order
 * */
public List<Category> getCategories() {
    List<Category> albums = new ArrayList<Category>();

    if (pref.contains(KEY_ALBUMS)) {
        String json = pref.getString(KEY_ALBUMS, null);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Category[] albumArry = gson.fromJson(json, Category[].class);

        albums = Arrays.asList(albumArry);
        albums = new ArrayList<Category>(albums);
    } else
        return null;

    List<Category> allAlbums = albums;

    // Sort the albums in alphabetical order
    Collections.sort(allAlbums, new Comparator<Category>() {
        public int compare(Category a1, Category a2) {
            return a1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(a2.getTitle());
        }
    });

    return allAlbums;

}

/**
 * Comparing albums titles for sorting
 * */
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Category> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Category c1, Category c2) {
        return c1.getTitle().compareTo(c2.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are facing problem during JSON parsing. Please add JSON also.

Comment: thnxx for taking time reading.. i don't know what to do.. here is the tutorial site that i have been following  http://www.androidhive.info/2014/08/android-building-free-wallpapers-app-part-1/

Comment: Your API is working? Please check response and post it.

Comment: how to check response

Answer (score 0):

From your stacktrace, its clear "feed" tag is not coming. Please post your JSON for more clearity which you are trying to parse.

```
if(response.has(TAG_FEED){
JSONArray entry = response.getJSONObject(TAG_FEED)
                    .getJSONArray(TAG_ENTRY);
....
```

Comment: i have been following this tutorial

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/08/android-building-free-wallpapers-app-part-1/   i m new in programming need every help

Comment: Can you post JSON structure which you are getting in response.

Comment: i m  flickr API not picasa... Splash Activity.java is where the Json call is happening..

Comment: Print response which is printing in Log.d(TAG, "Albums Response: " + response.toString());

Comment: here is log cat

Comment: sir can u pilz take time reading that tutorial and tell me where did i do wrong

Comment: Please put response of Api, which you are getting before parsing

Comment: sir do u mean this  D/Volley: [1513] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=186e87ccaabef1170b42cd5c0b5e6fc8&user_id=145840785@N03&format=json&nojsoncallback=? 0x86cad52e NORMAL 1> [lifetime=5148], [size=767], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]

Comment: Response of this URL. Add filter in your android monitor "Albums Response"

Comment: here is the url https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=186e87ccaabef1170b42cd5c0b5e6fc8&user_id=145840785@N03&format=json&nojsoncallback=?